# how Aggregate="sum" For TemplateColumns In RadGrid (Telerik) -> showing in footer

Tags: c#, sum, footer, radgrid

my TemplateColumn In RadGrid (Telerik) is like below :

```
                    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter TemplateColumn_Benefit"
                        HeaderText="Benefit" UniqueName="TemplateColumn_Benefit" FilterImageToolTip="Filter">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblBenefitInsideGrd" runat="server" Font-Size="11px" Text='<%# (bool)Convert.IsDBNull(Eval("Benefit")) ? "<span class=\"lblInsideGrd\">Empty</span>" : String.Format("{0:#,0 Dollar;#,0- Dollar}", Eval("Benefit")) %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="60px" />
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="60px" />
                    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

the showfooter property of RadGrid Is true ...
when add the below properties to this template column , so we will have an exeption ...

> **properties : FooterText="my sum" Aggregate="Sum"**
>
> **error message : Sum is not supported for type "System.Object"**

how can i have sum of such these columns in radgrid ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the **DataField="Benefit"** to the GridTemplateColumn.

```
               <telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter TemplateColumn_Benefit" DataField="Benefit"
                    HeaderText="Benefit" UniqueName="TemplateColumn_Benefit" FilterImageToolTip="Filter">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblBenefitInsideGrd" runat="server" Font-Size="11px" Text='<%# (bool)Convert.IsDBNull(Eval("Benefit")) ? "<span class=\"lblInsideGrd\">Empty</span>" : String.Format("{0:#,0 Dollar;#,0- Dollar}", Eval("Benefit")) %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="60px" />
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="60px" />
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: FooterAggregateFormatString="{0:C}", have a look at: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/aggregates/defaultcs.aspx